# Memory is not cleared after unbinding drawables and finishing

Tags: android, memory-leaks, activity-finish

I have a MenuActivity with a button "new game" upon pressing which this, MenuActivity should clean up completely so that you can't return to it and new activity should start. So the aim is to completely empty the memory that MenuActivity is holding. But I can see from the DDMS in eclipse that after the unbindDrawables() and finish() is called there is still 12621MB memory not released as you can see from the screenshot, but I need it to be 0 MB 
[image: DDMS screenshot]

activity_menu.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background" 
    android:id = "@+id/menu_layout" >

    <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:id="@+id/board_layout"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sound"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/on" 
            android:onClick="change"
            android:tag="on"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sound"
            android:background="@drawable/on" 
            android:onClick="change"
            android:tag="on"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/credits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:text="@string/credits"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="playCredits"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFF0"
                        android:visibility="gone"

           >
       </TextView>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delimiter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/credits"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/credits"
            android:text=" | "
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFF0" 
                        android:visibility="gone"
            >
       </TextView>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscribe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/credits"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/delimiter"
            android:text="@string/subscribe"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="subscribe"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFF0"
            android:visibility="gone">
       </TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fire"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:onClick="previewFireRoom"
    android:visibility = "gone"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/water"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/fire"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fire"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:onClick="previewWaterRoom" 
    android:visibility = "gone"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/earth"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/water"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:onClick="previewEarthRoom"
    android:visibility = "gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_menu"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

       >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="new game"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFF0"  
        android:onClick="newGame" 
        android:clickable="true"
      />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="resume"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFF0"
        android:onClick="resume"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:text="settings"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFF0"
        android:onClick="settings"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/walkthroughs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="walkthrou"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFF0" 
        android:onClick="walkthrough"
                android:clickable="true"
        />
                <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
        android:text="about"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFF0"
        android:onClick="about"
                android:clickable="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MenuActivity:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
    Intent intent;
    Typeface tf; 
    TextView newgame,resume,settings,walkthroughs,about;
    int walkthrough_board = R.drawable.walkthrough;
    int settings_board = R.drawable.settings;
    int about_board = R.drawable.about;
    RelativeLayout boardLayout;
    int on = R.drawable.on;
    int off = R.drawable.off;
    int walkthrough_clicked, about_clicked, settings_clicked = 0;
    private final String TAG = "Lifecycle ";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        newgame = (TextView)((RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.left_menu)).findViewById(R.id.new_game);
        resume = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resume);
        settings = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.settings);
        walkthroughs = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.walkthroughs);
        about = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.about);
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Livingst.ttf");
        newgame.setTypeface(tf);
        resume.setTypeface(tf);
        settings.setTypeface(tf);
        walkthroughs.setTypeface(tf);
        about.setTypeface(tf);
        about.setTypeface(tf);
        boardLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.board_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void start(View v)
    {
        intent = new Intent(this, FireRoomActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void newGame(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FireRoomActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.menu_layout));    
        this.finish();  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        try{
            Log.d("unbinding", view.toString());
            if (view.getBackground() != null) {
                ((BitmapDrawable)view.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
                view=null;
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }   
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public void resume(View view){
        changeColor(view);

    }

    public void settings(View view){
        if(settings_clicked == 0){
            settings_clicked++;
            if(walkthrough_clicked == 1){
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.walkthroughs));
                closeWalkthroughBoard();
                walkthrough_clicked = 0;

            }
            if(about_clicked == 1){
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.about));
                closeAboutBoard();
                about_clicked = 0;

            }
        changeColor(view);
        boardLayout.setBackgroundResource(settings_board);
        boardLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.sound).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.ad).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(settings_clicked == 1){
            changeColorBack(view);
            boardLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            closeSettingsBoard();
            settings_clicked = 0;
        }
    }
    public void walkthrough(View view){
        if(walkthrough_clicked == 0){
            if(settings_clicked == 1){
                closeSettingsBoard();
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.settings));
                settings_clicked = 0;
            }
            if(about_clicked == 1){
                closeAboutBoard();
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.about));
                about_clicked = 0;
            }
        changeColor(view);
        boardLayout.setBackgroundResource(walkthrough_board);
        boardLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.water).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.earth).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.fire).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        walkthrough_clicked++;}
        else{
            changeColorBack(view);
            walkthrough_clicked = 0;
            boardLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            closeWalkthroughBoard();
        }

    }
    public void about(View view){
        if(about_clicked == 0){
            if(settings_clicked == 1){
                closeSettingsBoard();
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.settings));
                settings_clicked = 0;
            }
            if(walkthrough_clicked == 1){
                closeWalkthroughBoard();
                changeColorBack(findViewById(R.id.walkthroughs));
                walkthrough_clicked = 0;
            }
        changeColor(view);
        about_clicked++;
        boardLayout.setBackgroundResource(about_board);
        boardLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.credits).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.subscribe).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
        else if(about_clicked == 1){
            changeColorBack(view);
            about_clicked = 0;
            boardLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            closeAboutBoard();
        }

    }
    private void changeColorBack(View view) {
        ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFF0"));

    }

    private void changeColor(View view) {
        ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDF00"));
    }
public void change(View view){
    String state = (String)view.getTag();
    if(state.equals("on")){
        view.setTag("off");
        view.setBackgroundResource(off);
    }
    else if(state == "off"){
        view.setTag("on");
        view.setBackgroundResource(on);
    }
}
private void closeAboutBoard(){
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.credits).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.subscribe).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
private void closeSettingsBoard(){
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.sound).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.ad).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
private void closeWalkthroughBoard(){
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.water).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.earth).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    boardLayout.findViewById(R.id.fire).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

}
```

Is there anything I'm missing in the unbindDrawableMethod() or some kind of memory leak?

Comment: You cannot control whether the garbage collector will be called. Maybe with flag "noHistory" on your AndroidManifest.xml you can anticipate that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a heap dump (after manually calling the GC from DDMS) and see what objects are being held on to using the Memory Analysis Tool. You can see where/if the memory is leaking. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You unbinddrawables is prolly the most aggressive I've seen and I'm not 100% it is worthwhile doing  it since you are calling `finish()` so lets look at that instead.

```
public void newGame(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FireRoomActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.menu_layout));    
    this.finish();  
    startActivity(intent);
    System.gc();  // call garbage collector
}
```

Now you should see your heap size change in DDMS/monitor.